# Intel TBB variable broadcast

Tags: multithreading, intel, tbb, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am using Intel TBB in order to create parallel Eratosthenes sieve. I have already done this in MPI in C language.

So, I want that my first thread (or task?) finds a prime number and then to broadcast to other threads so they all can "cross" this prime number from their part of an array.

Problem is: I cannot find a way to:

1. Detect first thread or task.
2. Make others wait until first thread or task broadcasts its prime number.

I have understood how i can use reduce etc, but i am not able to find this. I have found an example with some very fast Eratosthenes algorithm but there are no sync at all and algorithm is different and I need to parallel this exact default one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to understand the algorithm better so I did some [Googling on "parallel Eratosthenes" and found this](http://www.slideshare.net/adrian_panescu/parallel-prime-number-generation-using-the-sieve-of-eratosthenes), which uses similar language to your approach but doesn't explain the algorithm very well. Based on the description of the algorithm, it is poorly suited to a task-based API like TBB. Specifically, a task shouldn't block or wait on anything; it should be spawned when it has work to do and then run to completion. If we adapt the concept of your algorithm to a task-based approach, then it would look like this:

1. Create a vector to hold known primes. No need for concurrency here because it won't be written to concurrently. Populate it with a starter set (all primes up to 100?) Create an int to hold the largest checked number (set to 100).
2. Start a parallel_reduce of partitions of numbers from the largest checked number *p*+1 to some number no larger than *p*^2. Each parallel_reduce task will maintain its own vector of discovered primes. parallel_reduce will automatically subdivide these tasks into smaller tasks.
3. Within the parallel_reduce tasks, each one runs the serial sieve using the known primes vector to eliminate composite numbers in its range, and populates its own vector of discovered primes.
4. As the parallel_reduce joins two tasks, copy over all the primes from one task's vector to the other task's vector.
5. When you're down to one task, you've got a vector of primes to append to the known primes. Again, concurrency not needed here.
6. Update the int of the largest checked number to whatever you checked and go back to step 2 until you've got all the primes you want.

So there's no "broadcasting" of primes, nor any special job for the first task. There's just a series of parallel_reduces that get you more and more primes.

**UPDATE**

If you must pass information between tasks, the way to do it using TBB is to protect access to that data with a [tbb::mutex](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/doxygen/a00313.html).

However, the design challenge is not how to safely transfer data between tasks -- the challenge is **what is each task doing while it's waiting for data?** If the answer is "nothing" then you should not be using tasks. Tasks are designed to run to completion and should not be spin-waiting or blocking on a synchronization primitive like tbb::mutex. If you can design your tasks such that they iterate through work and periodically check for new data from other tasks in order to modify their approach, that will work fine. That same iterate-and-check-for-new-data approach can more easily be modeled with a series of parallel_reduce calls, as detailed above.

Comment: Yes, there are options to upgrade Eratosthenes algorithm and to remove broadcast etc. But my goal is not Eratosthenes sieve, goal is solving the problem of synchronizig taksks in Intel TBB. Like MPI can send sometging from one process or another, I want to do the same with Intel TBB. I want to avoid finishing one iteration on a number of tasks and then to create another set of tasks to do second iteration, I want to synchronize tasks while they working. Are there built in mechanism in TBB?

And thanks for Your answer.

Comment: As explained in my update above, tasks should not be synchronized, and therefore TBB provides no mechanism for doing so. Create tasks when you have work, let them complete and disappear when the work is done.